# How can I set a specific css property for Edge browser?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I have this css:

```
.records-table-row-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I have a problem with top positioning in Edge browser, been trying to solve it for nearly two days. I want to change top:50%; to top:19px; **Only for Edge browser**. The rest of the browsers should have top:50%;.

I've tried this :

```
  *::-ms-input-placeholder { 
    top: 19px;
  }
```

But Edge still takes the 50%.

Comment: _“But Edge still takes the 50%”_ - well that is little surprising, because `*::-ms-input-placeholder` formats the placeholder value that is shown inside a form field. This does not select your checkbox(?) _at all_.

Comment: I understood the usage incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe we can take a step back and find you why you need to target one browser only. If we solve that, perhaps we wouldn't need these ugly hacks.

Comment: The above css code centers the checkbox in Chrome, not in Edge. Moreover, the top:50% doesn't impact any of the two browsers, but something still makes it centered in Chrome. The problem is probably that the top property is in percentage, while the parent doesn't have a set height, instead the height is determined according to the checkbox. I hope that's clear.

Comment: Hm. Can you produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

For the checkbox, you can use `::-ms-check` selector only supported in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge. *An example usage below:*

```
input[type=checkbox]::-ms-check {
  top: 19px
}
```

Comment: Is there a method which doesn't include the type=checkbox?

Comment: I can see that you had created an another thread with the same code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075558/why-is-my-checkbox-not-vertically-aligned-in-its-parent In which you can check my testing result and was working similar in Chrome and Edge. Here I want to confirm with you, Is there any specific reason to apply different  CSS for Edge? generally people want similar result across the various browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  .records-table-row-checkbox {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}}
```

Comment: Please explain why and or how this solves the OP's question.